# SQL INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting this error

- InsertRecord(InsertRow): HResult of -2147217873 (80040e2f)
- Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server Error
- Description :  The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint `CK_ContactName`. The conflict occurred in database EPIC.7.5_GR_SM_ETLTRAINING; table dbo.ContactName.

The Statements

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContactName](
[UniqContactName] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] IDENTITY(65536,1) NOT NULL,
[UniqFixedContactName] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] NOT NULL,
[UniqEntity] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] NOT NULL,
[LkPrefix] [dbo].[DM_PREFIX] NOT NULL,
[FullName] [dbo].[DM_NAME] NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[MiddleName] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[LkSuffix] [dbo].[DM_SUFFIX] NOT NULL,
[DescriptionOf] [dbo].[DM_DESC_050] NOT NULL,
[Title] [dbo].[DM_TITLE] NOT NULL,
[Department] [dbo].[DM_DEPARTMENT] NOT NULL,
[UniqContactAddressMain] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] NOT NULL,
[UniqContactAddressEmployer] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] NOT NULL,
[UniqContactNumberMain] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] NOT NULL,
[UniqContactNumberEmailMain] [dbo].[DM_UNIQID] NOT NULL,
[ContactMethodCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[InformalHeading] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FormalHeading] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[BirthDate] [dbo].[DM_DATE] NULL,
[GenderCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[SSN] [char](9) NOT NULL,
[MaritalStatusCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[RelationToInsuredCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[LkLanguage] [dbo].[DM_LANGUAGE] NOT NULL,
[Comments] [dbo].[DM_COMMENT] NOT NULL,
[BillingDeliveryCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[ServicingDeliveryCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[MarketingDeliveryCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[CategoryCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[EmployerName] [dbo].[DM_NAME] NOT NULL,
[LkOccupation] [dbo].[DM_OCCUPATION] NOT NULL,
[HiredDate] [dbo].[DM_DATE] NULL,
[YearsEmployed] [smallint] NULL,
[YearsPriorEmployer] [smallint] NULL,
[FEIN] [char](9) NOT NULL,
[DUNSNumber] [char](9) NOT NULL,
[CdNAICSCode] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[CdSICCode] [char](8) NOT NULL,
[BusinessTypeCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[BusinessTypeOtherDesc] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[NumberEmployees] [smallint] NULL,
[NumberMembersManagers] [int] NULL,
[BusinessStartedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[NatureOfBusinessCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[NatureOfBusinessOtherDesc] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CreditBureauNameCode] [char](5) NOT NULL,
[CreditBureauNameOtherDesc] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CreditBureauIDNumber] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[DriverLicenseNumber] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
[LicensedState] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[LicensedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[LicensedMADate] [dbo].[DM_DATE] NULL,
[DriverTypeCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[GoodStudentCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[DriverTrainingCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[AccidentPreventionCourseDate] [dbo].[DM_DATE] NULL,
[CommercialExperienceBeganDate] [dbo].[DM_DATE] NULL,
[MatchClientNameOf] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[InsertedByCode] [dbo].[DM_INSERTUPDATEBYCODE] NOT NULL,
[InsertedDate] [dbo].[DM_DATETIME] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedByCode] [dbo].[DM_INSERTUPDATEBYCODE] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [dbo].[DM_DATETIME] NULL,
[Flags] [dbo].[DM_FLAGS] NOT NULL,
[ts] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[SIN] [char](9) NOT NULL,
[BusinessNumber] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[BusinessIDNumber] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[IBCCode] [char](6) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ContactName] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContactName]  
   WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_ContactName] 
   CHECK  ((
          [UniqContactName]=(-1) 
          AND [UniqEntity]=(-1) 
          OR  [UniqContactName]>(-1) 
          AND [UniqEntity]>(-1)
          ))
   GO
```

I have checked contactName db and all the rows from uniqueContactName all have a value above 65000, then for UniqEntity they all are above 65000 as well.

Does anyone have an idea why this would fail?

Comment: Can you add your INSERT statement to the original post please

Comment: When you combine AND and OR, please use parentheses so SQL Server doesn't have to guess what order of operations you meant...

Comment: Please add the create statement for `dbo.ContactName` as well.

Comment: Of course all the existing rows conform to the constraint: you aren't allowed to insert otherwise, as in your current situation.